# Block external javascript (Google Tag Manager) from being loaded by Selenium + Scrapy + Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy, google-tag-manager

I'm using Python + Selenium + Scrapy. What I want to achieve is that external javascript is not executed. For example Google Tag Manager.

If Google Tag Manager is loaded it could fire all kind of tags. Like facebook tags or for example, google analytics tags. Resulting data being sent to those platforms. That is what I want to prevent.

The Google Tag Manager [tag references](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js). [See.](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart)

I'm am using this code snippet. It's not clear to me how to define that `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js` should not be loaded.

```
    for row in result:
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=row.url,
            headers=headers,
            dont_filter=True,
            meta={'productIdentifier': row.productIdentifier, 'used_url': row.url, 'url_id': row.id},
            callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Easiest way might be to run a proxy on the same machine that blocks access to Google Servers. Some search on SO suggests that Selenium itself is not the best way to do this.

Comment: I managed to use a proxy for selenium, but I am not very happy with the solution. It means that everyone running the script should do additional installations/configurations. Would be better if i could add parameters or selenium options to block it.